# Django множественный ForeignKey между двумя приложениями

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin, django-orm, foreign-key

Здравствуйте! Столкнулся с проблемой в Django. У меня есть файл 
    students.models.py

```
from django.db import models
from groups.models import *


class Student(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Student'
        verbose_name = 'Студент'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Студенты'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    patronymic = models.CharField(max_length=30) #otchestvo*
    age = models.IntegerField(max_length=2)
    student_ticket = models.IntegerField(max_length=6)
    is_praepostor = models.BooleanField(default=False, 
                            verbose_name='Староста')

    def get_is_praepostor(self):
        if self.is_praepostor:
            return 'Староста'
        else:
            return ''

    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, null=True, blank=True)
```

И есть файл group.models.py

```
from django.db import models
from students.models import *


class Group(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Group'
        verbose_name = 'Группа'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Группы'

    number = models.IntegerField(max_length=3)
    praepostor = models.ForeignKey(Student, null=True, blank=True) 
                                                         #starosta*
```

В первом файле у меня стоит ForeignKey на Group, а во втором на Student. Проблема в том, что при интерпретатор считывает сначала с одного файла, а потом уже с другого. Следствием этого является ошибка а-ля 
    name "Group" is not defined или
    name "Student" is not defined

Каким костылем можно починить это, чтобы был форинкей с первой модели на вторую и со второй на первую?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Модели не могут операться на несуществующую модель, закоментируй в одной модели поле с ForeignKey, сделай миграцию, потом раскоментируй и опять миграция...
зачем ты делаешь такую связку?
данные модели group доступны с модели student
например при таком вызове: {{ student.group.number }} , в шаблоне...
ну это конечно смотря какая задача стоит...

Answer (score 0):

может `('Student', ...)` и `('Group', ...)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать еще одну модель "старосты" с двумя one-to-one полями к студенту и группе.